# How do I remove the same row from a multidime list

Tags: c#, .net, list, duplicates

I have two sets of data, and I put them in a multidime list as so.

```
List<List<string>> list1 = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> list2 = new List<List<string>>();
```

Structure of data:

```
list1 = {
          ["John Doe", 21, "USA"],
          ["John Brown", 20, "Canada"]
        };

list2 = {
          ["John Doe", 21, "USA"],
          ["John Mark", 22, "Brazil"]
        };
```

What can I do to remove {"John Doe", 21, "USA"} from both lists?

EDIT:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if(i < Results.Count())
    {
        sourceList.Add(new List<string>());

        foreach (DataColumn dtl in dtSource.Columns)
        {                    
            sourceList[i].Add(item.left[dtl.ColumnName].ToString().Trim());
        }
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        targetList.Add(new List<string>());

        foreach (DataColumn dtl in dtTarget.Columns)
        {                      
            targetList[j].Add(item.right[dtl.ColumnName].ToString().Trim());
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

The `result` variable is a union of two LINQ sets. The `Result` and `Result2` are DataRows from the `dtSource` and `dtTarget` DataTable parameters.

Comment: Your list cannot contain {"John Doe", 21, "USA"}. It is not an object and, moveover, it cannot contain integer items. The closest thing which can be in this list is: `[ ["John Doe", "21", "USA"], ["John Brown", "20", "Canada" ]`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find and remove all rows that are equivalent, or that you just want to remove one particular row from the lists that have it?  Also please show the exact syntax of how you're creating them.  What you've shown does not compile.

Comment: @DaxFohl The former. Edited. Added code on how I initialize the List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class StringListEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> lhs, List<string> rhs)
    {
        return lhs.SequenceEqual(rhs, StringComparer.Ordinal);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        // Something I cooked up real-fast. Shouldn't miss
        // any matching items but also not run sequence equal
        // in all the comparisons. You could improve it but
        // ensure it's fast.
        // Note that, the comparison operation is that first
        // the hashcode of two objects are compare and if they
        // match, then only the Equals method is invoked with them.
        return obj.First().GetHashCode();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    StringListEqComparer listComp = new StringListEqComparer();
    var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2, listComp);
    var list1Unique = list1.Except(intersect, listComp);
    var list2Unique = list2.Except(intersect, listComp);

    // Just in case you need them both in a single set:

    // var union = list1.Union(list2, listComp);

    // var result = union.Except(intersect, listComp); // (A U B) - (A n B)
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that he wants two things.  list1-list2 and list2-list1.  Or not.  But may as well add to your example just to cover the bases.

Comment: @DaxFohl: It's one and the same.
(A U B) - (A n B) = (A - B) U (B - A)
([See proof](https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/show-that-aub-anb-a-b-u-b-a/sets/3800314))

Comment: I know those two things are the same, but I don't think they're what the OP is looking for.  I think OP is looking for two distinct results: `list1.Except(list2, listComp`) and `list2.Except(list1, listComp)`.  Not a single result representing the disjoint union.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] {"John Doe", 21, "USA"});
list1.Remove(mylist);
list2.Remove(mylist);
```

The following link might help you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe it should be "21" instead of 21. But the List.Remove() function can be called like this.

Comment: It can be called, but it won't work. `List` uses default comparer which uses object equals which in turn uses reference equality. `new List<string> { "JohnDoe", "21", "USA" } == new List<string> { "JohnDoe", "21", "USA" }` is `false`. You cannot expect collections to be equal just because they store the same items (if only you don't implement own comparer or collection with overriden `Equals`).

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should find intersection elements in lists by [IEnumereble.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var intersection= list1.Where(a => list2.Contains(a)).ToList();
```

---

Better @AviTurner advised directly to use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Then remove from both lists intersection

```
list1.RemoveAll(i => intersect.Contains(i));
list2.RemoveAll(i => intersect.Contains(i));
```

Full code:

```
var Doe = new List<string>() { "John Doe", "21", "USA" };

List<List<string>> list1 = new List<List<string>>{
    Doe,
    new List<string>(){ "John Brown", "20", "Canada" },
};

List<List<string>> list2 = new List<List<string>>{
    Doe,
    new List<string>(){ "John Mark", "22", "Brazil" },
};

var intersect = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList().ToList();

list1.RemoveAll(i => intersect.Contains(i));
list2.RemoveAll(i => intersect.Contains(i));
```

[.netFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QpQme)

Comment: Why not use the 'Intersect' mwthod? its more explicit... `list1.Intersect(list2)`

Comment: I look at your `list1` and `list2` declaration lines and see this "Value assigned is not used in execution path" message before my eyes :)

Comment: Don't cheat and use the same object `Doe` when it's obvious the OP does not.

Comment: I tried the same fiddle, except, instead of using the `Doe` variable, I added the common values as a new List<string>.

Sadly, it didn't work.